# Debug assertion failed big allocation alignment -1 == 0

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I would like to ask whether somebody has experienced this problem and how to solve it. I searched on the internet, but I did not find anything helpful. What can it be caused by? Any ideas please? I have already tried to debug my application, but it's very difficult to find where it crashes. Another problem is that this error occurs only sometimes, and when it occurs, it's only at the end of my app. I need some hint please, thank you.

[image]

[Link to full-size picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDynw.png)

Comment: run it in debug mode, break when it crashes and see what is going on (call stack, variables, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Your application is trying to give back some memory allocated earlier at the end of your program, which is normal. However, according to the run-time library (xmemory module), there is a problem with the pointer that points to the memory to free.

Some possibilities:

- You could have some form of memory corruption in your program going on, since the run time library indicates a problem with the pointer passed to the 'free this memory' function.
  You can disable the check, but that would of course only mask the problem.
- Your project consists of multiple modules (DLLs) which mix different compiler settings. For instance that `HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` setting. Make sure all your modules were compiled with the same settings. Also modules created by others!
- You have compiled against the shared (DLL) version of the MSVC run-time
  library and there is some odd conflict between your project settings and the settings with which the run-time library was built.

In general I'd suggest you to have a look at the call stack debug window to get an idea which functions and objects are involved. Perhaps it's your program after all that corrupts memory somewhere.

Also, try to run it a few times and see if you start to see a pattern. For instance always the same function/object combination that causes the crash etc.

You can only see the call stack window when the exception occurs and the program pauses. This involves running the program in DEBUG mode under Visual Studio (from your screenshot it looks you run it outside of the debugger).